# How to represent pathways as mathematical graphs?

Tags: python, pathway, kegg

I would like to construct a mathematical graph: $G = (E,V, w(E))$ a graph with vertices, edges with weight on them [based on a KEGG pathway](https://www.biostars.org/p/85763/).

Is there a way to do that with existing tools? If not I will start to implement a Python module for that. My main question is what is the mathematical graph representation of pathways? Assuming the possible node types and the different connections?

I would like to transform a pathway to a graph because then one can run min-cut-max-flow algorithms and stuff like that as part of my [pathway analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathway_analysis).

Answer (score 1):

Pathways are generally directed graphs, which can be implemented in python using the `networkx` package. Note that there will be cycles in graphs.

Please note that there are large numbers of pathways analysis packages that already exist (both python and R packages but also just webservers), so I strongly recommend searching to see if something already exists before wasting time and implementing it yourself.

Comment: Pathways aren’t exactly directed graphs. There are different relationships (inhibition, enhancement,...) how to build a netwrokx’s graph out of it isn’t clear. And that is my main issue, how to build a graph given a KEGG pathway.

Comment: Basically my original question is how to transfer a KEGG pathway to a networkx object?

Comment: Inhibition and enhancement would be weights with different signs. For more complicated interactions standard graph representations simply wouldn't suffice.